# is it possible to move hard disks in raid 5 to pc without raid controller for accessing the information Temporarily?

Tags: hard-drive, raid5, hardware

I want to rebuild my array (RAID 5) for expansion. In the current configuration, I have 3x320GB hard disks giving me about 600 GB usable. I want to replace these hard disks with 3x1TB hard disks giving me about 2TB usable.

What I want to know, is there a way to  move hard disks in the hardware RAID5 from the server to my PC without raid controller and access the information on it temporarily?

Also, I want to know if I get an image of my current system, is it possible to restore the image to the same server with the updated RAID configuration?

Please respond to my Two above questions... help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to move hard disks in hardware raid 5 from a server to my pc without raid controller for accessing the information on it, Temporarily?

No - this will not be possible.

> if I get an image of my total current system with such as raid configuration and then restore on that same server with the raid configuration of 3 hard disks with the size of 1 TB of each one.is it possible?

Usually, yes.